# jq Invalid numeric literal at EOF updating json value to 0.0.x

Tags: json, shell, jq

i am trying to update my json file as following

```
jq  .attributes.DeployVersion.default=0.0.1 block.json > t.tmp && mv t.tmp block.json
```

which throws an error

```
jq: error: Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 5 (while parsing '0.0.0') at <top-level>, line 1:
.attributes.DeployVersion.default=0.0.1
```

while this:

```
jq  .attributes.DeployVersion.default=0.1  block.json > t.tmp && mv t.tmp block.json
```

works perfectly (the only difference is instead of 0.0.1 I use 0.1)

tried quotes, didnt work.

Comment: Show us _how_ you tried quotes. The obvious interpreteration would be that you tried a specific kind of quoting where the shell consumed the quotes without passing them to jq, but if you don't show us exactly what you tried we can't say what went wrong.

Comment: BTW, `jq --arg ver 0.0.1 '.attributes.deployVersion.default=$ver'` is another approach, since `--arg` interprets associated values as literal strings..

Comment: `0.1` is a valid number, `0.0.1` is not. What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes around both the version string and the whole expression:

```bash
jq -r '.attributes.DeployVersion.default="0.0.2"'
```

Or escape the quotes around the version string:

```bash
jq -r .attributes.deployVersion.default=\"0.0.2\"
```

You could also use `tostring` in a pipe, but it would be unnecessary.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh of course, thanks. I haven't had my coffee yet this morning.